# Convert plain array to Array of objects

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an array like this

```
let data = ['String1', 'String2', 'String3', 'String4']
```

I need to convert this array to an array of objects like so:

```
data = [ 
   {value: 0, label: 'String1'}, 
   {value: 1, label: 'String2'}, 
   {value: 2, label: 'String3'}, 
   {value: 3, label: 'String4'} 
]
```

How to achieve this most elegantly?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include [any attempt](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) at all to solve the problem. StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific roadblock you're running into in a [MCVE]. For more information, please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Comment: Take a look at the [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) function, including the full signature of the callback.

Comment: _"change this array to array of objects like this `<A>` or `<B>`"_ with `<A>` and `<B>` having the exact same structure o.O

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `map()`:

```js
 

const arr = ['String1', 'String2', 'String3', 'String4'];
const res = arr.map((label, value) => ({ value, label }));

console.log(res);
```